# I am getting wrong output in following parenthesis validation program of mine? What's wrong?

Tags: c++

```
bool isValid(string s) {
        stack<int> brack;
        int flag=0;
        int i=0;
        for (i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[' || s[i] == '{'){
                brack.push(s[i]);
            }
            if (s[i] == ')' || s[i] == '}' || s[i] == ']'){
                if (brack.empty()) {flag=1;break;}
                else if (s[i]==')' && brack.top()=='('){
                    brack.pop();
                }
                else if (s[i]==']' && brack.top()=='['){
                    brack.pop();
                }
                else if (s[i]=='}' && brack.top()=='{'){
                    brack.pop();
                }
                else {flag=1; break;}
            }
            if (brack.empty() && flag==0) return 1;
            else return 0;

        }
    }
```

I am getting wrong output for the following. I tried to do dry run and according to me output should be false.

```
Input:  "]"
Output:     true
Expected:   false
```

Comment: I suggest adding some spacing in the code. Come on, who finds `s[i]=='('||s[i]=='['||s[i]=='{'` readable? Wouldn't `s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '[' || s[i] == '{'` help track down the bug faster? :) Better yet, use descriptive constants.

Comment: What happens when you step through with the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

There's no return statement at the end. The given string sends execution to the first `break` on the first iteration, whereupon execution goes off the end of the function with no return value. That is undefined behavior, which you are observing as a meaningless return value.

I would recommend replacing the `flag=1; break;` with a `return false;`, and generally to clean up and comment the control flow so it's easy to see what should happen.

All the `flag=1;` instances determine that the return value will be `false`, so they can all be replaced with `return false;`.

Answer (score 2):

You're return logic is not in the right block. Perhaps some indentation and a little formatting will clear this up:

```
bool isValid(std::string s)
{
    std::stack<int> brack;
    int flag=0;
    size_t i=0;
    for (i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='('||s[i]=='['||s[i]=='{')
        {
            brack.push(s[i]);
        }

        if (s[i]==')' || s[i]=='}' || s[i]==']')
        {
            if (brack.empty())
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            else if (s[i]==')' && brack.top()=='(')
            {
                brack.pop();
            }
            else if (s[i]==']' && brack.top()=='[')
            {
                brack.pop();
            }
            else if (s[i]=='}' && brack.top()=='{')
            {
                brack.pop();
            }
            else
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        // WHY IS THIS IN THE FOR-LOOP
        if (brack.empty() && flag==0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    // THERE IS NO RETURN VALUE FOR ALL THOSE BREAKS HERE.
}
```